# How ray_cast ignores instantiated objects？

Tags: scripting

**My purpose is to use ray_cast to get all the objects on the ray, but I don't know how to deal with instantiated objects**

[image]
The following code will fail when it encounters an instantiated object:

```py
def x_ray_cast(context, depsgraph, origin, direction, ignored_name=None):
    ray_cast_objs = []
    hide_objs = []
    scene = context.scene
    i = 0
    if ignored_name is None:
        ignored_name = []
    while i < 100:
        (result, location, _, face_index, obj, _) = scene.ray_cast(depsgraph, origin, direction)
        if not result:
            break
        if obj.name not in ignored_name:
            ray_cast_objs.append({
                "name": obj.name,
                "location": location,
                "index": face_index
            })
        i += 1
        obj.hide_set(True)
        hide_objs.append(obj)

    for obj in hide_objs:
        obj.hide_set(False)
    return ray_cast_objs
```

The object is not in the view layer, but is displayed in the view layer as an instance of another object, how to make ray_cast ignore it?
Or how to get instantiated objects?
I don't know if I explained clearly

obj_a: not in view layer

obj_b: instantiated object (I don't know what to call it)

ray_cast will get obj_a, this is not what I want.

obj_a cannot be hidden because it is not in the view layer (or I don't know the method).

Therefore, obtaining obj_b through obj_a can also achieve my requirements, just hide obj_b.

Thanks！

**The case of empty objects:**

[image]

Comment: the key point, I think, is to define exactly what you mean by "instanciated object"?

Comment: @lemon Pictures express what I mean better，thanks

Comment: ok, so you want to raycast but ignoring instances (raycast like if they do not exist)?

Comment: @lemon Because ray_cast only returns the first object encountered first, here is obj_a, but the instantiated obj_a cannot be hidden, obj_b needs to be hidden, but I don’t know how to get obj_b, the result is that the object behind obj_a cannot be obtained